# Removed blank spaces however values are still not matching

Tags: sql, teradata

Doing a group by on a column gives this result:

> select *column*, count(*column*) from *table* group by *column*

```
column | count(column)

P      | 3123

P      | 145
```

I figured I must have a 'P' with trailing spaces. However, after using the function TRIM(column) and OREPLACE(column,' ',''), like so:

> select TRIM(*column*), count(TRIM(*column*)) from *table* group by TRIM(*column*)

.. I still get the same results.

Comment: is column a `CHAR`? If yes, try to `CAST` your column as `VARCHAR` ? It can also be an unbreakable space (these are invisible and not trimmed), or a different `P` character.

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Comment: Converting this to an answer then, it was faster than expected :)

Comment: Use `CHAR2HEXINT` to check for those characters: `A0` is a non-breaing space. You might then use `RTRIM(col, '20A0'XC)` to remove them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is column a `CHAR`? If yes, try to `CAST` your column as `VARCHAR`.

It can also be an unbreakable space (these are invisible and not trimmed), or a different `P` character.